# separate the same numbers php

Tags: php, mysql

how can I separate the same numbers with hr line? The numbers are pulled from the db row. 
example:

```
1
1
1
<hr>
----------
2
2
2
<hr>
---------- 
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM homepage order by bangdbs");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td align='left'>".$row['site_id']."</td>";
    if($site_id) {
        echo '<tr onclick="toggle(this)" style=""><td colspan="7"><hr noshade="" style="color:#F34105;"></td></tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are they already coming in groups from the mysql db, must the order be the same or can they be rearranged?

Comment: Please 1) describe what column `bangdbs` is, what's its relation to `site_id` and why you `order by` it 2) clarify if you want the `<hr>` inside the table or multiple tables (one per site_id) 3) is `<hr>` mandatory or a `style` trick would be just as good?

Comment: no, they are assigned to individual row.

Comment: bangdbs is the row I want the table to be sorted. Site id are the numbers I want to separate...

Comment: But if you `order by bangdbs` wouldn't that ruin the `site_id` ordering? I suggest you post some sample data to clarify this.

Comment: they already put this exact question on hold for this person about an hour ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411023/separate-the-same-number-php?rq=1

Comment: Don't re-post closed questions.

Comment: I have to re-post because the first one was on hold.

Answer (score 1):

```
$last = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 if( $last <> $row['site_id'])
   {
    echo "<hr>";
    $last = $row['site_id'];
   }
 echo $row['site_id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$previous_site_id = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td align='left'>" . $row['site_id'] . "</td>";
    if ($previous_site_id && $row['site_id'] != $previous_site_id) {
        // insert your <hr> construct here
        $previous_site_id = $row['site_id'];
    }
}
```

Note that, regarding the HTML, your sample is missing some points, and so is the solution. Anyway this is not really a problem, I'm just demonstrating how this could be done.

Comment: When a question "is missing some points", we usually post clarification comments to the question. Half-baked solutions isn't _the SO way_.

Comment: @geomagas - alright, will do next time. But I cannot post comments to the question as I don't have enough reputation (yet?).

Answer (score -1):

check theprevious value via sql and store them

```
<?php
$que = "SELECT * FROM homepage order by bangdbs";
$res = mysql_query($que, $con);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{ 
$idminus1=$row['id']-1;
$que2=mysql_query(select * from homepage where id='$idminus1' );
$previousvalue=$que2['site_id']

if($row['site_id'] == $previousvalue)
{
echo $row['site_id'];
}else{
echo "<hr>";


}}
```

?>

thats the entire code